# Server Socket is not working in my Flutter App and I am not able to listen any updates after connection

Tags: flutter, dart

### Flutter Server Sockets

I used Server Socket for my flutter app. But not able to listen or get any update . I even I don't know if its connected or not. Here is my code black for all socket work and i have called this in initState

```
      @override
  void initState() {
    startServer();
    super.initState();
  }

  late ServerSocket serverSocket;
  late Socket clientSocket;
  void startServer() async {
    print(serverSocket);
    serverSocket =
        await ServerSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 6000, shared: true);
    print(serverSocket);
    serverSocket.listen(handleClient);
  }

  void handleClient(Socket client) {
    clientSocket = client;
    clientSocket.listen(
      (onData) {
        print("Listening");
        print(String.fromCharCodes(onData).trim());
        setState(() {});
      },
      onError: (e) {
        disconnectClient();
      },
      onDone: () {
        disconnectClient();
      },
    );
  }

  void stopServer() {
    disconnectClient();
    serverSocket.close();
    setState(() {
      //   serverSocket = null;
    });
  }

  void disconnectClient() {
    clientSocket.close();
    clientSocket.destroy();
    setState(() {
      //clientSocket = null;
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you try to send any data to 6000 port from another app?

Comment: @AhmetKAYGISIZ I have tried and found no error even my device Ip and port are printing. How can we check if it is connected or not without listening ?